# How to setup trusted SSL for web servers in internal Windows network?

Tags: windows, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm developing a web application for use inside our *internal* Windows domain. I have 3 servers: `apps.mycompany.com` (primary), `api.mycompany.com`, and `files.mycompany.com`. Right now, everything works fine over HTTP. But I need to have these accessible over SSL/https to Windows desktop clients on the network (Chrome/Firefox/Edge) and iOS (Safari/Chrome).

I've set up self-signed certs using OpenSSL, and have configured nginx to where they respond correctly, and serve data. But, I'm constantly running into "not secure" / "invalid certificate" errors and "mixed content" (http/s) warnings that stymie my development. The errors on `api` and `files` are especially pernicious, as they just "break" things not obvious to the user.

I need a solution where everyone can simply hit `https://apps.mycompany.com`... and everything "**just works**", without user intervention (allowing insecure connections, manually adding certs, adding certificates to Trust stores, etc.)

Advice?

**EDIT:** I see this question was closed. Isn't setting up SSL/https an integral part of modern web development? (and yes, I had already asked my question on *Server Fault*).

Comment: Close? Already asked on Server Fault. Relevant here, as setting up servers for communication goes hand-in-hand with coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a root certificate that would be trusted by all your clients. Then you can sign server certificates with that "root" key so that server certificates would also be trusted.

This is the [example](https://deliciousbrains.com/ssl-certificate-authority-for-local-https-development/) how you can issue such certs.

More challenging task is to install this root cert to all your clients. You can ask your domain administrator to help you with that. Otherwise you will have to ask all your users to install that root cert (they will also probably have to be local administrators..)

Comment: Thanks for the great, detailed link. I was able to setup a root CA and use it to sign certificates. I still have 2 problems: 1. Removing the older certs I tried (can't find them in either Windows certificate store) and 2. As you mentioned, distributing to all network users.

But the question was "closed" (Um, psst, setting up SSL for secure WEB communication is an integral part of modern web development) so... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: (1) do you mean removing them from client machines? (2) I'm afraid here I cannot help you. This requires serverfault guys help indeed.

Comment: Yes... although I'm not even sure they're *on* the machine. Ah well, I'll re-post on SF. Thx again for the link.